# Using C++ on Jupyter

Tags: c++, jupyter, xeus-cling

I want to use the C++ kernel with Jupyter Notebook and lab on Windows 10. I have tried following the instructions at https://github.com/QuantStack/xeus-cling?fbclid=IwAR3EOC0yxcpe3hf0Lo82V1ioCZYQzagirnY-y4uVvWy6dOIpUL5TthHcx7M.

I am seeing the following output:

```
(base) C:\Users\Rogan>conda activate cling

(cling) C:\Users\Rogan>conda install xeus-cling -c QuantStack

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done

Solving environment: failed with current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.

Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done

Solving environment: failed


PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - xeus-cling

Current channels:

---


To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org
```

and the search bar at the top of the page is:

```
(cling) C:\Users\Rogan>
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem might be?

I would like to add Java, R, and C later on but am unable to even get C++ working.

Answer (score 1):

cling is not available on windows environment, so you should install Linux on your windows. Download WSL , and try above codes on Linux kernel.

Comment: Yeah, dump that windows right now